# How to speed up conditional MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

Query is:

```
SELECT RP.pID
  , (IF(RI.p01 = 54, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p02 = 16, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p03 = 54, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p04 = 92, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p05 = 34, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p06 = 51, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p07 = 62, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p08 = 98, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p09 = 14, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p10 = 25, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p11 = 34, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p12 = 67, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p13 = 81, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p14 = 29, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p15 = 24, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p16 = 45, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p17 = 72, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p18 = 86, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p19 = 25, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p20 = 95, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p21 = 92, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p22 = 31, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p23 = 24, 1, 0)
     + IF(RI.p24 = 78, 1, 0)) AS ATTP
FROM RP
LEFT JOIN RI
    ON RP.rID = RI.rID
    AND RP.nID = '1'
WHERE RI.p25 > ((RI.p27 + RI.p26) * 8)
ORDER BY ATTP DESC LIMIT 1000000;
```

In real situation there are 27 of such ifs and query takes 25-35 seconds to complete.

Table in which I check these conditions is relational and grows up everyday by ~50 000 records.

To speedup WHERE part of query I have Primary index on iNR,
but **how to speedup these IFS?**

Execution plan:

[image]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `RI` (
  `rID` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p01` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p02` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p03` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p04` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p05` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p06` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p07` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p08` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p09` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p10` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p11` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p12` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p13` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p14` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p15` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p16` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p17` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p18` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p19` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p20` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p21` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p22` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p23` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p24` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p25` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p26` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p27` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ils` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci;

CREATE TABLE `RP` (
  `pID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_lithuanian_ci;
```

Comment: Is it possible to persist that column instead of computing that every single time you query it? I don't know efficient it would be, but you can also try to use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: "...Generated columns are supported by the NDB storage engine...", in my option it is InnoDB

Comment: Show the query plan.

Comment: I would add an column, for persisting the result.  And I would add a BEFORE INSERT / BEFORE UPDATE trigger that calculate the result.

Comment: Don't.use.triggers. You'll regret that in the future.

Comment: BIG NO to triggers. I am suffering from them right now - causing locking issues (despite InnoDB), deadlocks and eventual update failures due to these locks. I am finally working on to remove all the triggers, and handle them in the application code.

Comment: Another approach - do the calculation in application, not in database.

Comment: Can it be faster to do calculations in PHP not in SQL?

Comment: I use IFs on query, because that way I get ORDERED list I need. I think PHP will be much mo slow to sort a list.

Comment: It'd help if you would add table DDL statement and exact query.

Comment: The execution plan you posted cannot belong to the SQL query you show. The execution plan shows evidence of a JOIN between two tables, and an ORDER BY, neither of which appear in the query you showed. Please help us help you! Post the actual execution plan for the SQL query, and post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table in the query.

Comment: I wouldn't discount triggers just yet; most issues people end up having from triggers usually result from too much being done by the trigger. Using them for something simple, like populating a "calculated field", should barely be noticeable (could slow down updates and inserts due to the calculation being performed). _To me, saying triggers should be ruled out because they can cause problems, is a bit like saying a hammer should be ruled out because it messes up screws._

Comment: The execution plan suggests that 'WHERE RI.p25 > ((RI.p27 + RI.p26) * 8)' is causing a filesort. Does every query use this logic, or do different versions use different columns and/or multiplications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now when we got real query and DDL, it makes it so much easier to help you! :)

Try creating the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_RP_nID_rID ON RP (nID, rID);
```

This should eliminate full RP table scan that is now happening. It should add a significant boost but there still may be room for improvement.

Also, I think that your `LEFT JOIN` behaves as `INNER JOIN` because you still have a filtering condition in `WHERE` clause.

I saw that InnoDB let's you index expressions. If you're always querying exactly same columns, you could try creating an index on RI table that would include rID, p25 ((p27 + p.26) * 8) and whole expression in select statement. This technically should persist calculation.

But this solution will work later, after mysql update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Created an index, but no difference on execution time.

Comment: Does execution plan change?

Comment: Yes, new key is used instead of primary key and second query have extra "Using index". In my opinion the problem is RI table :( Is here any option to solve it width indexes?

Comment: I saw that InnoDB let's you index expressions. If you're always querying exactly same columns, you could try creating an index on RI table that would include rID, p25 ((p27 + p.26) * 8) and whole expression in select statement. This technically should persist calculation.

Comment: I know how to make index on column, but how to make it on query result?

Comment: Documentation says that you can create such an index `CREATE INDEX idx2 ON t1 ((col1 + col2), (col1 - col2), col1);` so if try this with your query. Index both expressions as last keys in index.

Comment: Shows: Syntax error near '((p27+p.26)*8))' at line 1

Comment: All query: CREATE INDEX TESTAS ON (rID, p25,((p27+p.26)*8))

Comment: Yes there is synrax issue. Redundant dot between p and 26

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179571/discussion-between-evaldas-buinauskas-and-vykintas).

Answer (score 1):

**Fix 1** :Indexing all 4 columns a,b,c, & d will help processing faster.

**Fix 2** : May be adding a trigger which updates another column in the same table when value is inserted or updated will solve the problem.

both fix are temporary ones please provide more info on the problem statement on why you need the if's in query
hope it helps

Comment: If you have clustered index (and that's usually the case for a primary key), then your table is already indexed properly.

Comment: Tried to create a new table and add a tiger to table RI (which used for IFs), but find out a bigger problem to this... Every RI table row has a different result for every RP table row. RP table at the moment have ~75 000 rows, so ~50 000 new rows to RI table tigers ~3 750 000 000 updates on that new table :( This query does only a small amount of job in whole system and in this way uses most of server time :( looks like tigers this time isn't a solution :(